# Is there any point to specifying any fields other than "Id" when using WorkItemTrackingHttpClient.QueryByWiqlAsync()?

Tags: c#, azure-devops, tfs, tfs-sdk

I've been looking at several Microsoft code samples for using  [`WorkItemTrackingHttpClient.QueryByWiqlAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.workitemtracking.webapi.workitemtrackinghttpclientbase.querybywiqlasync?view=azure-devops-dotnet), and they all specify a number of fields in addition to the "Id" field.

For example, [from this code sample](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-dotnet-samples/blob/main/ClientLibrary/Quickstarts/dotnet/WitQuickStarts/Samples/ExecuteQuery.cs):

```
Wiql wiql = new Wiql()
{
    Query = "Select [State], [Title] " +
            "From WorkItems " +
            "Where [Work Item Type] = 'Bug' " +
            "And [System.TeamProject] = '" + project + "' " +
            "And [System.State] <> 'Closed' " +
            "Order By [State] Asc, [Changed Date] Desc"
};
```

Then the code goes on to use this query:

```
WorkItemQueryResult workItemQueryResult =
    workItemTrackingHttpClient.QueryByWiqlAsync(wiql).Result;
```

But then the following code extracts *only* the IDs from the query and uses them to get the actual work items, using `workItemTrackingHttpClient.GetWorkItemsAsync()`:

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();
foreach (var item in workItemQueryResult.WorkItems)
{
    list.Add(item.Id);
}
int[] arr = list.ToArray();

//build a list of the fields we want to see
string[] fields = new string[3];
fields[0] = "System.Id";
fields[1] = "System.Title";
fields[2] = "System.State";

//get work items for the id's found in query
var workItems = workItemTrackingHttpClient.GetWorkItemsAsync(arr, fields, workItemQueryResult.AsOf).Result;
```

I discovered that you only need to `"Select [Id] FROM workitems ..."`, because only the ID is actually used. In fact, I can find no direct way of accessing the other fields in the `WorkItemQueryResult` results returned from `QueryByWiqlAsync()`.

So what am I missing? Why do all the Microsoft code samples specify a variety of columns for the query, but then just ignore them all? Is it just a mistake, or is there some fundamental reason that I'm unaware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that they copied the WIQL expression from an existing query.

As the REST API only returns the IDs and the .NET client libraries for Azure DevOps are just a thin wrapper around the REST API, the client libraries can't surface data that isn't returned by the REST API.

See the example response (shortened by me) from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/wiql/query-by-wiql?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP)

```json
{
  "queryType": "flat",
  "asOf": "2014-12-29T20:49:34.617Z",
  "columns": [
    {
      "referenceName": "System.Id",
      "name": "ID",
      "url": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/wit/fields/System.Id"
    },
    {
      "referenceName": "System.Title",
      "name": "Title",
      "url": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/wit/fields/System.Title"
    },
    {
      "referenceName": "System.State",
      "name": "State",
      "url": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/wit/fields/System.State"
    }
  ],
  "sortColumns": [
    {
      "field": {
        "referenceName": "Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority",
        "name": "Priority",
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/wit/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority"
      },
      "descending": false
    },
    {
      "field": {
        "referenceName": "System.CreatedDate",
        "name": "Created Date",
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/wit/fields/System.CreatedDate"
      },
      "descending": true
    }
  ],
  "workItems": [
    {
      "id": 300,
      "url": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/wit/workItems/300"
    },
    {
      "id": 299,
      "url": "https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/_apis/wit/workItems/299"
    }
  ]
}
```